# Variance of number of tails minus heads

Tags: probability

Given $X_n$ is a random variable that equals the number of tails minus the number of heads when n fair coins are flipped, what is the Variance of $X_n$ ?
I tried to solve it

Comment: How did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ be independent r.v.s such that $Y_i=1$ if $i$th toss is head and $0$ if $i$th toss is tail.

Then $Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ is the total no. of heads and $n-Z_n$ is the total no. of tails.

Thus we want to find $Var((n-Z_n)-Z_n)=4Var(Z_n)=4\sum_{i=1}^nVar(Y_i)=4nVar(Y_1)$ because $Y_i$ are i.i.d.

Now $Y_1\in Bernoulli(0.5)$ hence $Var(Y_1)=0.5\times0.5=0.25$.

Hence $4nVar(Y_1)=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the uniform distribution over $\{-1,+1\}$, and let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n \sim \mathcal{D}$ be i.i.d. copies of $\mathcal{D}$. Then $X_n$ has the same distribution as $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$. Hopefully you can compute the variance of $Y_i$ and deduce the variance of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n = T - H$ and $T + H = n$, the number of tosses. Adding together we have $X_n + n = 2T$. The variance is then given by
\begin{equation}
Var(X_n) = 4 Var(T) = n.
\end{equation}