# Suppose $X$ be the random variable that denotes the number of heads minus the number of tails when $10$ unbiased coins are tossed. Find the variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose an unbiased coin is tossed $10$ times. Let $X$ be the random variable that denotes the number of heads minus the number of tails. What is the variance of $X$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333848/variance-of-number-of-tails-minus-heads) seems to have the solution but I do not understand what it says. I am looking for an explanation of the link I shared.

I am still sharing my solution so as to show I am not posting it without trying it at all.

$\text{E}[X] = \displaystyle\sum_{h=0}^{10} \left(\frac{{10 \choose h}}{2^{10}} (h - (10-h))\right) = \frac{1}{2^{9}} \displaystyle\sum_{h=0}^{10} {10 \choose h} (h-5) = 0$

$\text{E}[X^2] = \displaystyle\sum_{h=0}^{10} \left(\frac{{10 \choose h}}{2^{10}} (h - (10-h))^2\right) = \frac{1}{2^{8}} \displaystyle\sum_{h=0}^{10} {10 \choose h} (h-5)^2 = 10$

This gives $\text{Var}[X] = \text{E}[X^2] - \text{E}[X]^2 = 10 - 0^2 = 10$. This is how I did, considering the PMFs.

Comment: There are three answers under the question you linked to, and also that question is a duplicate of a question that has two answers. So you already have five answers. Which parts of them did you understand and which did you not understand? Can you give any clues about why you did not understand the parts you did not understand? It may help to know if you have any knowledge about the variance of a sum of iid variables of known variance, or the variance of $2Y$ where $Y$ has known variance.

Comment: @DavidK I don't understand how the variance suddenly gets the scalar $4$ before it. This is what user Landon Carter and user Gregory did. 

That said, user (Prof.) Yuval Filmus' answer looks fascinating and I don't see what exactly he is trying to say. 

I don't understand i.i.ds, I haven't read that.

Comment: Variance of $(aX)$ = $a^2$ Variance of $X$.  In other words, if you multiply all of your numbers by 7, your standard deviation should go up by a factor of 7, which would make the variance go up by a factor of 49, since variance is the square of the standard deviation

Comment: Same question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062048/expected-value-and-variance-of-x-y-where-x-is-the-number-of-boys-and-y-is/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the random variable that denotes the number of heads out of the 10 coin tosses. Since the coin is unbiased and different tosses are independent of each other, we can model $Y$ as
$$Y \sim Bin(n, p),$$
where $n = 10$ and $p = 0.5$.

Since $X$ is the random variable that denotes the number of heads minus the number of tails, we have that
$$X = \underbrace{Y}_{\text{number of heads}} - \underbrace{(n - Y)}_{\text{number of tails}} = 2Y - n.$$
To get the variance of $X$, first we would like to recap [two basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance): if $a$ is a constant, then

(1) $\text{Var}(X + a) = \text{Var}(X)$;

(2) $\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$.

Back to this problem, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(X) &= \text{Var}(2Y - n)\\
&= \text{Var}(2Y) \quad & \text{by property (1)}\\
&= 2^2\text{Var}(Y) \quad & \text{by property (2)}\\
&= 4\text{Var}(Y)\\
&= 4np(1-p),
\end{align*}
where the last step follows from the [variance of Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Plugging in $n = 10$ and $p = 0.5$, we have
$$\text{Var}(X) = 4np(1-p) = 4 \times 10 \times 0.5 \times (1-0.5) = 10.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Argument:** $n = H+T,$ implies $T = n - H,$ so $X = H- T = H - (n-H) = 2H - n.$ Also, $E(X) = E(H-T) = E(H) - E(T) = n/2 - n/2 = 0.$

Then $Var(X) = Var(2H-n) = 4Var(H) = 4(n/4) = n = 10.$

**Simulation** with 10 million 10-toss sessions.

```
set.seed(2021)
n = 10;  p = 1/2
h = rbinom(10^7, n, p)
t = n-h;  x = h-t;
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 0.0010386    # aprx E(X) = 0
[1] 10.00229     # aprx Var(X) = 10

summary(x)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
 -10.000000  -2.000000   0.000000   0.001039   2.000000  10.000000 

hist(x, prob=T, br = (-11:10)+.5, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Simulated Dist'n of H - T")
```

[image]

Comment: I like this simulation and thanks for the overall explanation. Is this R by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

$E[X] = \sum x \cdot P(x)$
The probability is as you seem to indicate, $${10 \choose h}(\frac{1}{2})^n \frac{1}{2}^{10-h} = \frac{{10 \choose h}}{2^{10}}$$
If you wanted the number of heads that should be multiplied by $h$ and summed.  As you want the number of heads minus tails, your first calculation is correct, $E[X] = 0$, which makes sense by symmetry anyway.
I repeated your calculation of $E[X^2]$ and got the same answer you did, which appears to be correct according to the other answers.

Comment: $x = h-t$ for $(h,t)$ that satisfies $0 \leq h,t \leq 10$ and $h+t = 10$. From there, I set $x_i = h_i - (10 - h_i) = 2h_i - 10$ where $h_i = i$ and goes over $0$ through $10$. $X$ is the number of heads minus the number of tails.

Comment: Ah you're right, my apologies, I misread the question.